# Embeddable unit testing framework for mixed Windows app

Tags: c++, unit-testing

I want to test portions of a very complex app which includes both a major native Windows component and a substantial WPF GUI. Due to complexities I can't detail, it is impossible to run the native portion independently nor can I isolate the areas I want to test (spare me the lectures, we're talking a huge legacy code base and we **do** have refactoring plans).

I'm looking for a unit test kit I can invoke on the native side but must be able to run with the app launched with the managed portion initialised. That seems to rule out the [run executable feature](http://www.cfix-testing.org/unit-testing-framework/windows/doc/ExeTargets.html) of the [cfix](http://www.cfix-testing.org/unit-testing-framework/windows/) Windows unit test kit. I really like their philosophy, like [WinUnit](http://winunit.codeplex.com/), of using DLL compilation as a way to add the reflective capabilities missing in C++ and gain a more NUnit-like experience.

Ideally, I want something like WinUnit running within the application code and generating an HTML report.

I'm trying to introduce more TDD and having things as lean as possible is important.

Comment: For now, a combination of inspiration and a little architectural refactoring means I worked out how to isolate most of the code in a library with a testable boundary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is C++/CLI.

You can use managed code test frameworks such as mbUnit, NUnit and xUnit.Net with C++/CLI code and they work fine. The contents of the tests then call native functions from the native libraries.

There are two minor gotchas:

1. There's a bug in xUnit.Net that prevents their InlineData attribute being repeated in C++/CLI, as discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3116911/attribute-cannot-be-repeated-in-c-cli-but-ok-in-c).
2. You sometimes have to be careful about the working directory of the test runner or to explicitly copy native DLLs as the *shadow copy* approach some use will only get managed dependencies.