# Attribute cannot be repeated in C++/CLI but OK in C#?

Tags: c#, c++-cli, xunit.net

I'm getting `error C3095: 'Xunit::Extensions::InlineDataAttribute': attribute cannot be repeated` in C++/CLI code but not C#.

[xUnit.net](http://xunit.codeplex.com/) looks like the answer to my prayers - a modern unit test framework with GUI working with C++/CLI. However, using their approach to parameterised testing gives me the error C3095 as shown below.

Any ideas?

I'm using the latest xUnit.net 1.6 with Visual Studio 2008SP1.

```
using namespace Xunit;
using namespace Xunit::Extensions;

public ref class ParameterisedTestClass
{
public:

    [Theory]
    [InlineData("Kilroy", 6)]
    // uncomment to cause c3095 [InlineData("Jones", 5)]
    void PropTest(String^ msg, int msgLen)
    {
        Assert::Equal(msg->Length, msgLen);
    }
};
```

the equivalent in C# is fine

```
using Xunit;
using Xunit.Extensions;

public  class ParameterisedTestClass
{

    [Theory]
    [InlineData("Kilroy", 6)]
    [InlineData("Jones", 5)]
    public void PropTest(String msg, int msgLen)
    {
        Assert.Equal(msg.Length, msgLen);
    }
};
```

Comment: Using ILDASM or Reflector, what is the value of InlineDataAttribute's AttributeUsage?

Comment: @Richard: See my answer, which links to the latest source code. They haven't changed since 2008.

Comment: I've opened a bug here: http://xunit.codeplex.com/workitem/9690

Comment: Thanks, Brad. I'm flat out for the next couple of weeks and then intending to revisit this issue.

Comment: This also happens in F#. I've upvoted the codeplex issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hmmm... I looked at the defs [here](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/CSharp/Testing/xUnit.net/Xunit/Extensions/InlineDataAttribute.cs.htm) and [here](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/CSharp/Testing/xUnit.net/Xunit/Extensions/DataAttribute.cs.htm), and reproduced them (cut-down) below; the inheritance of `AllowMultiple` via `DataAttribute` works fine in C#:

```
class Test
{
    [InlineData]
    [InlineData]
    static void Main() { }
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
class DataAttribute : Attribute {}

class InlineDataAttribute : DataAttribute { }
```

So if it isn't working for C++/CLI, I guess C++/CLI simply isn't processing the implied `[AttributeUsage]`. You should file a request against Xunit asking them to make the `[AttributeUsage]` explicit on `InlineDataAttribute`.

Answer (score 7):

My guess is that this is due to inheritance, and one of the compilers getting it wrong.

[`InlineDataAttribute`](http://xunit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/ecb57b287fe1#Main%2fxunit.extensions%2fDataTheories%2fInlineDataAttribute.cs) inherits from [`DataAttribute`](http://xunit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/ecb57b287fe1#Main%2fxunit.extensions%2fDataTheories%2fDataAttribute.cs). Now `DataAttribute` is declared to allow multiple instances:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
```

but `InlineDataAttribute` doesn't have any explicit `AttributeUsage` attribute itself. I *suspect* the C++ compiler isn't spotting the inherited AllowMultiple... or it's possible that it *shouldn't* be inherited. I can't find any detailed documentation about the inheritance of [`AttributeUsageAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attributeusageattribute.aspx) itself - although it has `Inherited=true`, so I guess it *should* be inherited completely by `InlineDataAttribute`...

Answer (score 1):

I repro with this C++/CLI snippet:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets::All, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
ref class BaseAttribute : Attribute {};

ref class DerivedAttribute : BaseAttribute {};

[Derived]
[Derived]    // Error C3095
ref class Test {};
```

Clearly this is a bug in the C++/CLI compiler.  I don't see it reported at connect.microsoft.com.  Doing so yourself probably isn't worth the effort, the language is in maintenance mode.

Possible workarounds are editing the source code of xUnit to assign AllowMultiple again or to create your own InlineDataFixedAttribute that inherits InlineDataAttribute.

Comment: Why do you say "the language is in maintenance mode?"  For VS2010, native C++ code was the focus, working toward the next version (or maybe even next service pack) I understand that C++/CLI is the focus for Visual C++ team.  Certainly they've promised to make Intellisense work in C++/CLI again, implement C++0x (which means anonymous methods and closures in C++/CLI as well bringing it to parity with C# in these areas), etc.

Comment: I'm with Ben, whilst C++/CLI has been relegated to being an "interop language" as such it is vital and I don't see any reason for it to go away. To a certain extent, focusing on this role gave me hope for its long-term future. Depends on whether you consider "maintenance mode" means it will never get new features or if it will just reliably be fixed - I'd be fairly happy with the latter ;-)